# How to Fetch Exact Location from Latitude And Longitude in angular?

Tags: geolocation, location

I want to know The Exact Location From Latitude And Longitude which ,I can get from geolocation But is there any free Google APIs which can give Exact Location Name Of that Place From that latitude and Longitude

I Have tried the below Api for fetching the location but Could not found The exact location of the place

https://api.bigdatacloud.net/data/reverse-geocode-client?latitude=xyz&longitude=xyz&localityLanguage=en

I got the Country name State and city But Could not found the
exact near by
Place name